# Is there any form I should fill for taxes in the UK

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom

I moved to London at the beginning of January to start working at my new job.
At the moment I got payed but I'm not sure if I should do anything related to taxes.

Is my employer going to take care of everything or am I supposed to fill any form?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about living in the UK and not about expat issues.

Comment: @StrongBad It's very much on-topic in my opinion. In particular, in many countries, locals would usually be known by the tax office and receive a pre-filled tax return or something whereas newcomers might need to do something above and beyond that or not know exactly for what they are liable.

Comment: @GaëlLaurans and for those countries the question would be on topic. In the UK the process is the same independent of your nationality and how long you have been in the country. In my mind this is a life in the UK question.

Comment: @StrongBad But the person asking doesn't know that… For me that makes the question on-topic, even for countries where it turns out that there is no difference in the end.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are an employee, then you'll get your P60 form around the end of the tax year (5th April). Usually (if you are a basic employee, e.g. not self-employed or similar) you don't have to do anything with that. [More information on the gov's site.](https://www.gov.uk/paye-forms-p45-p60-p11d/p60)

Also you should get a payslip every time you are paid (either on paper or electronically), where you can check the status of your current tax contributions. Please note that because you started to work in January, you are only working for 3 months in the country before the end of the tax year, meaning you might get a higher take-home-pay, as the income tax is calculated on your whole income in the actual tax year, and not monthly.